# mapStateToProps ownProps return undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

Good afternoon, everyone. I've encountered a problem which I am unable to resolve.

I've tried to follow the [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect), to find an answer on SO, but failed so far.

`ownProps` is returning undefined. This is the "grandparent" (Homepage):

```
      {<Switch>
        <Route exact path="/computers">
          <MacBookList />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/computers/:id" component={MacBookCard}>
          <MacBookCard />
        </Route>
      </Switch>}
```

This is MacBookCard, a "grandchild":

```
import React from 'react'
import { fetchMacBooks } from '../actions/macBookActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
const MacBookCard = (macbook) => {

return (
    <div>
        ...
    </div> 
    )
  }
  const mapStateToProps = (state, {ownProps}) => {
      console.log(state)
      console.log(ownProps)
  }
  const dispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      fetchMacBooks: () => dispatch(fetchMacBooks())
    }
  }
  

  export default connect (mapStateToProps, dispatchToProps)(MacBookCard)
```

I am very grateful for your insight!

Comment: I think the mapStateToProps signature is `const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => { ... }`. In other words, you shouldn't be destructuring `ownProps`

Comment: More info from the documentation. https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#ownprops-optional

Comment: I've tried it your way, unfortunately I am getting the same `undefined` response, when `console.log(ownProps)`. I must be doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Nick's answer above, you can still do destructuring directly from the parameter list but make sure that the prop names that you declare are actually used by the component.

```
 const mapStateToProps = (state, { id, macbook }) => {
      console.log(state);
      console.log(id); // should be a valid prop of MacBookCard
      console.log(macbook); // should be a valid prop of MacBookCard
  }
```

Comment: That does make sense, however, I am still getting `undefined` for both `id` and `macbook`.

Comment: You have to define the props that are actually used in the component, id and macbook are just examples.

Comment: Ismaeli, that was exactly what I've missed. Thank you so much! I will accept your answer above, since I have no way of accepting this one. :)